# How to invoke an static method which contains generics types from an static generic class

Tags: reflection

I'm using Reflection to work out my project classes with the Generics from a third party, however, I keep getting the error "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true." when I try to Invoke an static method from an static generic class which contains generics invocation.

Third Party code looks like this

```
public interface INestedGeneric<TResult>
{
    INestedGeneric<TResult> DoSomethingElse();
}

public static class GenericClass<TResult> where TResult : new()
{
    public static INestedGeneric<TResult> DoSomething()
    { return new NestedClass<TResult>(); }
}

public class NestedClass<TResult> : INestedGeneric<TResult>
{
    public INestedGeneric<TResult> DoSomethingElse()
    { return new NestedClass<TResult>(); }
}
```

My code looks like:

```
public class Someone
{
    private int _integerProperty;
    private string _stringProperty;

    public int IntegerProperty
    {
        get { return _integerProperty; }
        set { _integerProperty = value; }
    }

    public string StringProperty
    {
        get { return _stringProperty; }
        set { _stringProperty = value; }
    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Type classType = typeof(Someone);
        Type theclass = typeof(GenericClass<>); theclass.MakeGenericType(classType);
        Type theinterface = typeof(INestedGeneric<>); theinterface.MakeGenericType(classType);

        MethodInfo dosomething = theclass.GetMethod("DoSomething", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        dosomething.Invoke(null, null);
        dosomething = null;

    }
```

Any idea how to invoke the method strictly in this scenario? I have read and try the help from other posts, but didn't work.

Thank you so much...

I already figure it out. The solution was to use the type provided by the MakeGenericType method.

Like this:

```
        ...
        Type theclass = typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(classType);
        Type theinterface = typeof(INestedGeneric<>).MakeGenericType(classType);

        MethodInfo dosomething = theclass.GetMethod("DoSomething", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        dosomething.Invoke(null, null);
        ...
```